# Java latency and bandwidth measure from client to the server

Tags: java

Is there a way to write java client code to measure latency and bandwidth for any server?

Comment: In short: yes. But this is not a question that is suitable for this site. Please read the Help section (upper right part, just next to the search box)

Comment: You can't do an actual (ICMP) ping, but you can open a socket and send some data.

Comment: Voting to close. It's offtopic as it's asking about library

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a literal ping (to measure latency) you can use a library like [icmp4j](http://www.icmp4j.org/).

For bandwidth it's not as simple because the server would have to be sending you data that you can measure, e.g. a large file.

Comment: this example generate "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Pointer". I have added icmp4j library.